# Vuejs router-link changes dynamically

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have multiple templates in my project, with a fairly simple url structure.

`/startpage/`

`/startpage/test_1`

`/startpage/test_2`

In my 'App.vue' I made a template, which is shown on every page in my project. That template includes a button, which is supposed to act like a 'Home' button, named 'Projects'.

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <router-link :to="/startpage/"><button class="Project">Projects</button></router-link>
    </div>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>
```

When I'm on the startpage (`localhost:4545/#/startpage/`), the button has the target `localhost:4545/#/startpage/`.

But when I'm on another page, for example `localhost:4545/#/startpage/test_1`, the button suddenly has the same url as the page I'm on.

Why does the router change the link dynamically and not keep the target `/startpage/`?

Comment: have you tried removing the trailing slash?

Comment: Yes. It still changes, when I go to a different page.

Comment: What happens if you remove the ":" before to ?

Comment: how about trying without any slashes at all

Comment: @OliCrt Thank you very much! That works! I thought the ':' were necessary for the router-link tag.

Comment: @LLJ97 You're welcome :) you might wanna check v-bind in the doc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-link-props), you either need to use binding or not:

```
<!-- literal string -->
<router-link to="home">Home</router-link>
<!-- renders to -->
<a href="home">Home</a>

<!-- javascript expression using `v-bind` -->
<router-link v-bind:to="'home'">Home</router-link>

<!-- Omitting `v-bind` is fine, just as binding any other prop -->
<router-link :to="'home'">Home</router-link>
```

So it *should* be that you don't need to use `:`, **or** use a string literal. Currently it tries to use it as a variable, which of course it not present.